# Prevent browser from forced scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

I have a problem, I'm working with draggable elements in my page, the entire parent elements has `overflow: hidden` and it's working fine, but, if I force the page to scroll dragging elements outside, an unwanted scrolling will happen. You can see it in action in the fiddle bellow dragging the gray box to the right...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a6vzhk2z/

[image: error from pen]

EDIT: it is expected that half of the element can go outside the page

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```
$(".draggable-box").draggable({
    containment: [-100,100,windowWidth - 200,100]
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqWwOJ)

EDIT: Maybe this would be nicer:

```
$(".draggable-box").draggable({
    containment: [0,100,windowWidth - 200,100]
});
```

EDIT #2: The problem isn't the box. The mouse is the problem. It only happens if the mouse moves outside the window. Prevent the mouse going out of the window should solve the problem.

Comment: I've thought about it, however, it is expected that half of the element can go outside the page.

Comment: I think there is no way to prevent this, because it don't fire an event.

Answer (score 1):

So when you drag the box all the way to the right, it increases the screen size slightly beyond the scoll bar, correct?

This may not be what you want, but when I subtracted an additional 100 from the windowWidth, it seemes to have fixed the problem:

```
$(".draggable-box").draggable({
    containment: [-100,100,windowWidth-200,100]
});
```

Comment: i said the same and he already wrote: "it is expected that half of the element can go outside the page"

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, my solution was an position to the parent element.

This is my new SCSS for `#container`:

```
#container{
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  overflow: hidden;

  #text{
    @include full-height();
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o8Lrpzb2/1/